# laravel: http request gave error

Tags: php, laravel

My idea is to send https request to all the URLs saved in my database using a model called `Notifications`.

```php
class guzzleController extends Controller
{
    public function guzzle() {
        $client = new Client();
        $notes=Notification::all();
        $response = $client->get($notes);
        $response=$response->getStatusCode();
        var_dump($response);
    }
}
```

For some reason the get method expects string, and it gave me an error:

> InvalidArgumentException in functions.php line 62: URI must be a string or UriInterface

How can I fix this? Anyone with a better idea?
this is actually my notification class

```
namespace App;
use App\Status;
use App\Notification;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Notification extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id','website_url','email','slack_channel','check_frequency','alert_frequency','speed_frequency','active'];

    public function statuses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Status')->withPivot('values')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just saying you're using a `Client` class but there's no trace of use statements here because you're not showing all the code that is needed for us to figure this out. We don't even know what are the `get` method parameters. My guess is that you're getting an array of `Notification` class entities back from this statement: `$notes=Notification::all();`.

So first of all you should be iterating over them and then you call the client on each one of them. But also then you may need to provide just a string to the `get` method. Can't say how since there's no code about the `Notification` class as well.

**EDIT:**

Given the code you provided I think you should try with something like this:

```php
class guzzleController extends Controller
{
    public function guzzle() 
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $notes = Notification::all();

        foreach ($notes as $note) {
            $response = $client->get($note->website_url);
            $response = $response->getStatusCode();
            var_dump($response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: namespace App;
use App\Status;
use App\Notification;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Notification extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = ['id','website_url','email','slack_channel','check_frequency','alert_frequency','speed_frequency','active'];

 public function statuses(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Status')->withPivot('values')->withTimestamps();
 }

Comment: You should be updating your question rather than posting the code as a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, the guzzle client's `get()` method accepts either a string or a `UriInterface` implementation. You're fetching the data from `Notification` model (which returns a `Illuminate\Support\Collection` not an array of URIs) and feed it directly to the client. You need to prep your data for the client. Something like this:

```
use Notification;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class GuzzleController extends Controller
{
    public function guzzle() 
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $notes  = Notification::all();

        // To do this in a more Laravelish manner, see:
        // https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-each
        foreach ($notes as $note) {
            // Assuming that each $note has a `website_url` property  
            // containing the URL you want to fetch.
            $response = $client->get($note->website_url);

            // Do whatever you want with the $response for this specific note
            var_dump($response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it makes sense. instead of get($note->url), shouldn't it be get($note->website_url). becaues the name of the urls is save in the notifications table in a column website_url?

Comment: Yeah, sure. I didn't know it's `website_url`.

Comment: one question though. instead of sending the https request for all the urls, it sends only for the first one.

Comment: Please update your question, not the answers. It's probably because you're overwriting the `$response` in the foreach loop. How do you know that it only sends the request for the first note?

Comment: Sorry! there was an error in the code i wrote. i debugged it and  it works perfectly! tnx